# What is the sense in giving names to constructors

Tags: java, c++, constructor, abstraction

I have been using C++ and Java for several years now. One thing which I can't seem to understand is that why do we need to provide constructors of a class a name? For instance, if I have to define a class `FOO` in C++/Java, I'll be forced to provide `FOO` as the constructor name. However, since constructor is never explicitly called, what is the sense in compiler forcing me to provide it a name after all.

The abstraction paradigm dictates, we hide unnecessary details from programmers. This is the reason, constructors don't have a return type, since it's already well-defined what a constructor has to return. In the same spirit, why can't we just give a generic name to constructors of all classes - for instance anything meaningful, like `initialize()` or maybe just nothing and just arguments `( [arg [,arg]] )`

I hope, I'm able to express myself. If someone have any definitive answers, kindly let me know.

Comment: As an interesting sidenote, PHP does have a generic name for constructors `__construct`

Comment: This question is a better fit on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++ standard (12.1) (emphasis mine):

> Constructors **do not** have names. A special declarator syntax is used to
> declare or define the constructor. The syntax uses:
>
> - an optional decl-specifier-seq in which each decl-specifier is either a function-specifier or constexpr,
> - the constructor’s class name, and
> - a parameter list

In C++, you are not providing a name, you are writing special syntax which was decided by the language creators to declare a constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But still, from a language design perspective, it's not optimum to have this syntax enforced. I completely understand that constructors will not be represented like other methods, that their name is discarded, but still having to do extra work seems tedious. Imagine a class where we have 10 overloaded versions. A concise notation would have been a better design choice.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: That can be debated. In C++, C# and Java, the name of the class is used. I personally think that is the most logical way.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: Is it really such an onerous task to copy/paste the class name once for each constructor and destructor?

Comment: @Blastfurnace It's just a general discussion on design of programming language. Nothing taxing about coding anyway. IDEs makes this task easy.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: You said "having to do extra work seems tedious" but I guess we agree that isn't a real issue.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question at all. the user still writes down the class name when declaring the constructor. users dont care what the standard internally defines.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `this doesnt answer the question at all` I think the problem isn't with my answer, but with the question itself. I vote to close this question as "not constructive" because it will only solicit debate and opinions.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ constructors do not have names(C++03 12.1), however since constructors are essentially defined as functions, it was logical to name them in some way.
Naming them anything other than the class name would have added new keywords and hence eventually they were named same as the class name.
In short, It was a logical decision which avoided new keywords and at the same time ensured intuitiveness.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But here I'm talking about not adding additional keywords, but simply to remove a constraint, which seems unnecessary detail. For instance, somebody mentioned that in PHP we have some notation __construct, to define a constructor, which is common across all classes. In python also we have __init__ keyword to define a constructor like functionality. These names makes constructor emerge more explicit in their meaning. Anyways, I think it's a design decision and maybe it can be improved in future iterations. I was just pondering over it and decided to solicit opinions on it.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: The language examples you cited do add new keywords, When C++ was designed there was conscious effort to keep the keywords to a minimum thus using such a new keyword would be an overhead. **There is no specific constraint** . Other language would force you to use a keyword,C++ forces you to use the class name(*in the process not inventing a new keyword*).Also, every language is designed with some specific language grammar,One cannot argue aspects of this grammar, its simply because the designer though/wanted so.

Comment: C++ would need more than just one name. Destructors and copy constructors currently don't have names either. But let's be realistic: any decent IDE can use color-coding. Seeing a class name colored as a function name is a clear visual hint that you're dealing with the ctor.

Comment: i think using the "this" keyword would work fine. havent checked with a compiler writer though

Answer (score 1):

it's a standard for the language, if you want to have a generic name for constructor then try to learn another language or maybe create your own language. =p

Comment: Waiting for 125 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

For Java and C++, the constructor name must be the same as the class name. Besides, you know it is a constructor, because it does not declare a return type. This way to declare a constructor helps you to declare a method which name is `__init__`, `initialize`, or `__constructor`. This is not possible in Python, for example, because it uses `__init__` as constructor name.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are special member function and constructor always returns the memory address  created by 'new' operator. Since one function returns only one thing at a time so no other value can return from constructor.
   It is the java standard to define a constructor name same as the class name.

Comment: I understand the semantics, but my question is on design level. Why force a programmer to define a name after all. I think, you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

*First*, you don't have to write a constructor.
if you don't write one - the compiler will create a default constructor for you.

*second*, sometimes you do have to use one (for example, if you have final class variables they have to be initialized upon creation of the object). In this case you have to write a constructor and you will use it when you instantiate the object.

```
public class Foo {
    final int a;

    public Foo (int val){
        this.a = val
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo (23);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your line of thought. The syntax Java adopted is just a historical artifact.

In newer languages that support OOP, this redundancy is generally absent. Scala calls it `this`*, F# calls it `new`*, Python calls it `__init__`, Ruby calls it `initialize` etc.

---

<sub>* Auxiliary constructors anyway. The primary constructors in these languages are class arguments themselves.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

since you can't call the constructor explicitly, what's the purpose of giving a special name to it? and about constuctors having a name same with the class: constructing can only be performed in a function so constructor is a function. and since it's a special function, among other class functions it should have a special signature. language designers wanted them to be named same with the class.